# Selecting an element host based on the value of an attribute

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular 4 application, I have a requirement to dynamically create two components and inject them into the template. I have successfully done this with one component, but now I need to add another.

I have this directive:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[component-host]',
})
export class ComponentHost {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

and I have this HTML template extract:

```
<!--- HTML --->
<ng-template component-host></ng-template>
```

and this `ViewChild`:

```
// TypeScript
@ViewChild( ComponentHost ) componentHost: ComponentHost;
```

This all works great, I have code that creates the component and inserts it. However, now I have the requirement for an additional component to be injected dynamically in the same template. Currently, I have to separate directives but this is clearly not an optimal solution. Is it possible to select the element in `@ViewChild` using the value of the attribute? Something along the lines of:

```
<!--- HTML --->
<ng-template component-host='replace1'></ng-template>
<ng-template component-host='replace2'></ng-template>

// TypeScript
// How do I select the element with an attribute with a certain value?
@ViewChild( ComponentHost ) componentHost: ComponentHost;
```

I am creating my components like this:

```
protected createComponent( componentType: Type<any>, componentHost ): any {
  const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory( componentType );
  const viewContainerRef = componentHost.viewContainerRef;

  viewContainerRef.clear();

  const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent( componentFactory );
  componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

  return componentRef.instance;
}
```

It is important to me to be able to `detectChanges()` once the component has been created. I have tried various permutations but none work. Any ideas?

If I use hash selectors, then `const viewContainerRef = componentHost.viewContainerRef;` returns null.

Comment: show your code how you insert the components. and why do you use directive instead of a template-ref like this `<ng-template #component-host1></ng-template>` - `@ViewChild('component-host1', {read: ViewContainerRef}) componentHost: ComponentHost; `

Comment: @Maximus I have followed the cookbook at https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader. My code is almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you're using a component to select `ng-template` element. You can use template-reference for it:

```
<!--- HTML --->
<ng-template #component-host-replace1></ng-template>
<ng-template #component-host-replace2></ng-template>

// TypeScript
@ViewChild('component-host-replace1', {read: ViewContainerRef}) host1: ViewContainerRef; 
@ViewChild('component-host-replace2', {read: ViewContainerRef}) host2: ViewContainerRef;
```

Comment: I have followed the cookbook at https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader. My code is almost identical. I have added my component creation code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ViewChildren? ViewChild will only give you first children

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildrenDecorator#description